# How to search items in CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an ObservableRangeCollection that consists of a few items. How can I conduct a search in the ViewModel of the Page?

Edit:

ObservableCollection in ViewModel:

```
private ObservableRangeCollection<Smetka> _smetki = new ObservableRangeCollection<Smetka>();
        public ObservableRangeCollection<Smetka> Smetki
        {
            get { return _smetki; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _smetki, value); }
        }
```

And this is the CollectionView in the View:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Smetki}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding LaunchDetailPage}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSmetka}" Grid.Row="1">

</CollectionView>
```

I have been searching for a VM search example for a while now. I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me with one.

Edit 2:

This is what the app looks like normally.

[image]

When Search Criteria is given the ObservableRangleCollection should display only the Smetkas, who meet the Criteria.

[image]

[image: This is how the app looks now]

After removing the Search Criteria it should display all the Smetkas, who meet the new criteria. If the String is empty or whitespace it should display all of them.

Comment: use LINQ like you would do to search any collection.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your question? This seems like a simple question about MVVM.

Comment: @FilipePilettiPlucenio I have added the code I use.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the problem. You can upload the complete data, but cannot filter any properties by text?

Comment: You could refer to the update below and have a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to retrieve the item from your list ?

If yes,just use LINQ,for example:

```
public class PLU
{ 
  public int ID { get; set; } 
  public string name { get; set; } 
  public double price { get; set; } 
  public int quantity {get;set;}
}

public static ObservableCollection<PLU> PLUList = new ObservableCollection<PLU>();
```

retrieve like:

```
PLU item = PLUList.Where(z => z.ID == 12).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update**:

```
string filter = "9";//the filter you input
var searchItems = new ObservableCollection<Smetka>(Smetki.Where((smetka) => smetka.Id.Contains(filter))); // Assuming the property is Id.
```

then you could replace the Smetki with searchItems .